# SVN move root one level up

Tags: svn

I have project like this

```
project_dir
└── htdocs
```

SVN checkout was executed on htdocs dir, so that is root dir where i have this svn info

Working Copy Root Path: /home/user/project_dir/htdocs
URL: svn://mydomain.com/something

Now i want to change SVN root from htdocs to one level up, so i have checkout into project_dir as root, and not htdocs.

Is there some easy way to do this and to keep all files in htdocs intact (i have there some ignored and non versioned files too..) ?

I have tried to execute this in htdocs dir:

```
svn switch --relocate svn://mydomain.com/something svn://mydomain.com/something/htdocs
```

but that didn't worked, bc of this error

```
svn: E195009: 'svn://mydomain.com/something/htdocs' is not the root of the repository
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's `relocate` you need. You need a checkout of `svn://mydomain.com/something`, and you cannot relocate or switch in a checkout of `svn://mydomain.com/something/htdocs` to do that.

What you can do, is checkout `svn://mydomain.com/something`, delete the `htdocs` directory inside it, and move there the existing directory. You just have to move directories around a little bit, but it should work. For example:

```
cd /home/user
mv project_dir project_dir.bak
svn co svn://mydomain.com/something project_dir
rm -fr project_dir/htdocs
mv project_dir.bak/htdocs project_dir/
svn st project_dir
```

If moving directories around is not an option, here's another way:

```
cd /home/user
svn co svn://mydomain.com/something something_new
mv something_new/.svn .
svn revert -R .
```

Comment: Moving directories around is what i would like to avoid in this case, because it's important project with many millions of daily hits (and there is non versioned files too, i was thinking that there must be way to keep all as it is)... My hope was that there is some way in SVN to just change SVN root dir to one level up, so i have something like this inside project_dir:
htdocs, composer.json, file.something... and to keep all in existing svn trunk.

Comment: I think that we will switch to the GIT, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about restructuring your repository structure or your working copy?

I'd be very hesitant about restructuring the repository although it's possible. However, from some of your statements, it sounds like you want to restructure your working directory. In versions of Subversion 1.6 and below, this was fairly simple to do since each directory in your working directory tree had a complete `.svn` directory for that directory level. Chopping off the *root* wouldn't cause any issues.

However, in Subversion 1.7, the layout of the working directory was changed. There's only a single `.svn` directory in the root, and it's for the entire working directory. Chomping off the root will break your working copy.

But, then what is the issue you're trying to solve? If you only make your changes in `htdocs` subdirectory tree, you can commit at that level. It makes not one whit of difference what you're working directory tree looks like when you do a commit. The commit history will be the same.

If the issue is disk space, use `--set-depth` to remove all other projects from your working directory. Or, bite the bullet, and do a new checkout of the htdoc's directory:

```
$ svn co svn://mydomain.com/something/htdocs
```

The `relocate` command is used when the server itself is moved. For example, I recently reconfigured my Apache httpd server to move my repository URL from this:

```
http://svn.server.com/svn/CorporateServerTRD/trunk/...
```

to

```
http://svn.server.com/trd/trunk/...
```

That's where `svn relocate` comes into the picture. This way, you could move your repo to a different server, or switch from `http://` to `svn://` or visa versa, and users won't have to redo their checkouts. The `svn relocate` command is fast because there's only one tiny piece of information that must be changed.

There's another command `svn switch` (which in earlier versions was also the *relocate* command too) that switches your working copy from one URL to another:

```
$ svn co svn://mydomain.com/something/trunk/htdocs
```

Whoops... I should have done my work on the 3.2 branch:

```
$ svn switch svn://mydomain.com/something/branches/3.2/htdocs
```

You can try that on your working directory, but it certainly won't be any faster than a new checkout.

If you really, really want to restructure your repository, it's probably easiest by making a working directory:

```
# First, checkout the repository root with the first level of directories in it

$ svn co --set-depth=immediates $REPO_ROOT

# Now let's get all of the directories and files immediately under htdocs
$ svn up --set-depth=immediates htdocs

# You now want to remove everything from the root of your repo execept
# for the htdocs directory. If you're using BASH, you can do the following.
# If your on Windows, you may have to do the delete one at a time.
# shopt -s extglob
$ svn delete !(htdocs)

# Now move all the files and directories in the current `htdocs` to the
# root of the repository
$ svn mv htdocs/* ..

# Delete the now empty htdocs directory
$ svn delete htdocs

# Commit your changes
$ svn commit -m"Make 'htdocs' my new root."
```

Now, your `htdocs` contents will be the root of the repository. However, your commit history will be more difficult to follow and merging or reverting will be much harder too. It's the reason why you don't blindly move and restructure your repository without a really good reason.

What would be a good reason? Maybe adding in `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags` directory if you setup your repo without them. Maybe if your trunk gets so messed up that you've abandoned it and the history on it is now meaningless. Even there, I'd be hesitant to do so. I'd rather *merge* my way back to a good trunk rather than delete and move a branch to that place.

Comment: Basically issue here is that i want to keep file structure as it is (even to remember what files in htdocs are ignored or not in SVN), just i want that project_dir become SVN root dir, instead of htdocs (currently SVN root dir).

I will see with other people working on that project, but maybe it will be easiest to simply move to GIT and do git init in project_dir.

Reason for making this changes is to have other files and dirs also in same SVN repo, next to htdocs, for example composer.json and other... Thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: Even though it doesn't look like this answer has gotten a lot of views, I found it to be very helpful/educational for my situation.  I think this should be the accepted answer.  I know we're not supposed to say "thanks" in a comment... but thanks David!